# Is there a way to open this kind of ratchet with no visible screws and no visible retainer rings?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

I'd like to know if [this kind](https://www.diy.com/departments/magnusson-ratchet-handle/1785061_BQ.prd) of ratchet with no visible screws is serviceable in anyway, i.e. if it can be at least opened to clean it. (The ring on the rear serves as selector). It tried prying up the ring with a flat screwdriver (with and without the release button depressed) but it doesn't seem to budge (up). I have to wonder how they even assemble the thing...

Here are some hi-res photos (well, as hi-res as SE would allow) of the actual head:

[image: r]
[image]

Contrary to the answer/suggestion below there are no visible retainer rings on either side. There is room for a 0.05 mm feeler to go all way around, and for the 0.1mm feeler in one spot (where the handle curves) under the rear selector. But even there a 0.15mm would not go in all the way that the 0.1mm one does. The gap space might look bigger, but that's only an illusion because the spinning parts are rounded on both sides. There's no retainer ring that I can feel anywhere.

Here's photo of the rear with the eject button depressed (and held that way with pliers grabbing the inner pin tip). As you can see the real ring is also one solid piece of [painted] metal, with nothing obvious to remove there...

[image]

(By the way, I managed to clear enough of it with the feelers, so it doesn't make a rock-dust-grinding noise anymore, but the question how to open this still remains unsolved.)

Comment: Doesn't have a snap ring or possibly a c-clip retaining the mechanism in the handle? You need to add a front and back close-up view of the ratcheting mechanism.

Comment: @Jeeped: no visible retainer rings either. Even with the release button depressed, nothing removable is visible. The rear ring is a pretty thick metal.

Comment: If you pry off the black plastic hub from the switching side, it *may* reveal some sort of retaining circlip. However, I won't take responsibility for any damage. Why is it important to take apart anyways? I've had ratchets that spent 30 years on a salt water fishing boat and I just use them without problems. If you need one to take apart, just buy a snap-on.

Comment: @Jeeped: the rear [selector] ring is also [painted] metal (like I said)... Unless there's some plastic or thin metal element inside, I'm not sure how that ring it could snap on to something (although I did try prying it up). I guess I'll wait until it fails then and cut it for enlightenment purposes. (It was exposed to some pretty thick cement dust.)

Comment: Why do you think it needs cleaning?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar one and if you look at the square drive side there is a retaining ring which holds the ratchet mechanism in place.

Take care when prising the ring out - I use a small bladed screwdriver.